# Checkstyle check ParameterNumber without Override Methods

Tags: eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I am writing my own Checkstyle Plugin for Eclipse. I want to check the number of parameters from Methods, but I don't want to consider the Paramaters of @Override Methods.

That's my current Code in my XML File, at the moment it checks all Methods:

```
<module name="ParameterNumber">
            <property name="max" value="7" />
            <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF" />
</module>
```

Edit: I don't want to use SuppressWarnings-Notation

Comment: Are you actually writing a new plugin (i.e. a new check), or are you trying to *configure* Checkstyle to do what you want?

Comment: @Thomas i am writing a new plugin, which also includes a checkstyle config

Comment: Still unclear to me what you are asking. Anyways, the *ParameterNumber* check cannot be *configured* to ignore @Override methods. But if you are writing your own, it's your code.

Comment: @Thomas yes, I recognized that, but how to do that? Any Example Codes?

Comment: There is a good example and in-depth explanation in the [Checkstyle docs](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution that I posted on google groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/checkstyle/5IK0DwLUC6c